# PHP explode \r and \n characters

Tags: php, explode

I have an excel template which is used to fill in data. I export this to CSV. One of the fields contains a new line character. When done on a mac it returns a `\r` instead or `\n`

When I try to explode that text as below:

```
$skillsets = explode("\r", $j['skillsets']); // works with CSV exported from MAC
$skillsets = explode("\n", $j['skillsets']); // works with CSV exported from WIN
```

Is there any way I can check for either of them and make sure my explode works for both `\r` and `\n`?

Comment: use preg_split or preg_match instead so you can pass in more than 1 delimeter

Comment: why not use an str_replace to convert any combination of `\r\n` or `\n\r` to a straight `\n`

Comment: For csv there is a specific function for manipulate the date http://php.net/manual/fr/function.fgetcsv.php

Comment: You might also want to check into [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php), and the corresponding setting to auto-detect line endings.

Comment: @MarkBaker Comment is the best solution. Was abt to write that as an answer.

Comment: This can't be the right place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest would be to use `preg_split`:

```
$skillsets = preg_split('/(\r|\n)/', $j['skillsets']);
```

Using a regular expression is not necessary, but this is a very simple case, and you only need to change one line of code.